# Timer keeps running on pageload without content showing

Tags: javascript, css

On the static version at http://www.dkhomes.nl/ the page loads fine, but on another version at http://www.dkhomes.nl/dkh/ the timer keeps running without showing the content even though its there.

There's an error in console but i don't know which image that's supposed to be i have to look for.

Answer (score 1):

You trying to access cross domain origin: http://screencast.com/t/JEBtvYvQ

Read this article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: So, should i add the js script and that's it, i don't understand it very well.

Comment: I don't that error but this: Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html. Line 1

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved: i had a wrong name for the footer.